# Use the filter of a form in a SQL query via VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, filter, vba

I'm having trouble using the `filter by form` in a SQL query via VBA in Access 2013. I didn't create the Access forms but was commissioned to correct an issue. Also the client told me that it worked in the previous Office versions and that the Access-Database hasn't been changed in the past few years. So it seems, that Access 2013 does something differently. But I couldn't figure out what.

As you may understand below, the **red highlighted button** should un-/check all the **yellow highlighted checkboxes**. This works perfectly fine until I add a filter by form (**red box** at the bottom of image). Ironically I encountered this issue only by filtering the **red underlined field** `Programm_IDFS`. Filtering by other fields works fine.
[image: Form whose filter acts strange]
This query should uncheck the checkboxes but it fails because the value of `strFilter` is:

> ((Lookup_Programm__IDFS.Name="ad1incl"))

This may work for filtering, but it doesn't work as SQL restriction.

```
UPDATE dbo_tbl_ThisForm
SET dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Checkbox = 0,
    dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Statusoffen = '0'
WHERE dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID = " & gsVariable5 & ")
AND dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID IN
        (SELECT Auftrag_ID
        FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions2
        WHERE Auftragstyp = " & Me.kfAuftragstyp & "))
AND " & strFilter & "
```

This query should check all the checkboxes. It works because I hard-coded all the values (actually this is only necessary for `strFilter`).

```
UPDATE dbo_tbl_ThisForm
SET dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Checkbox = -1,
    dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Statusoffen = '-1'
WHERE dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID = 544)
AND dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID IN
        (SELECT Auftrag_ID
        FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions2
        WHERE Auftragstyp = 9))
AND dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Programm_IDFS = 35
```

If you need more information feel free to ask.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

When running the query with `strFilter=((Lookup_Programm__IDFS.Name="ad1incl"))` I get the following error:

> "Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1."

I now just figured out, that the un-/checking also doesn't work for the field `Funktion`. This and  the `Programm_IDFS` field are both foreign keys of data type **int** in the table `dbo_tbl_ThisForm`.

When filtering by the field `Fachbereich` it works to un-/check the checkboxes, since that field is of data type **varchar**, so `strFilter` is set to a valid value:

> ((dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Fachbereich="Steuern"))

Those foreign keys both link to separate tables. Now how can I solve this? Do I need to include those tables in my query? Can I change something on the form?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get rid of the preceding `Lookup_`-thing I decided to deal with it in VBA.

I used following VBA-Code to change the part with **Lookup_[field]** to a corresponding SQL-query:

```
If InStr(strFilter, "Lookup_") <> 0 Then
    If InStr(strFilter, "Programm__IDFS") <> 0 Then
        strFilter = Replace(strFilter, "(Lookup_Programm__IDFS.Name", "dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Programm_IDFS = (SELECT ID_Programm FROM dbo_Programm WHERE Name")
    ElseIf InStr(strFilter, "Funktion") <> 0 Then
        strFilter = Replace(strFilter, "(Lookup_Funktion.Beschreibung", "dbo_tbl_ThisForm.TF_Funktion_IDFS = (SELECT TF_Funktion_ID FROM dbo_TF_Funktionen WHERE Beschreibung")
    End If
End If
```

So for example if I use a filter on the **Programm_IDFS** field it will change

```
((Lookup_Programm__IDFS.Name="ad1incl"))
```

to

```
(dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Programm_IDFS = (SELECT ID_Programm FROM dbo_Programm WHERE Name="ad1incl"))
```

This way it can update all the checkboxes. I didn't find a way how to remove the `Lookup_`-thing nor why it only affects certain combo boxes. The main thing is that it works now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Recently I ran in to a similar problem with an application that was upgraded to Access 2013 after running fine under Access 2003.  I noticed that the form's combo box controls shared the exact same name as their source fields.  Suspecting that name ambiguity might be confusing Access when it generates the filter, I renamed the controls (gave them a "cbo" prefix).  That seemed to fix the problem for most cases.

Some users still see it happen at times, but then I haven't removed all the ambiguous names yet: I fixed only the ones that are being used for filtering.  I plan to do that others in the next release.

It shouldn't hurt to give the control's different names from their data source fields, and I've always found it makes it easier for me to understand the applications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repositioning the filter, like:

```
UPDATE dbo_tbl_ThisForm
SET dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Checkbox = 0,
    dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Statusoffen = '0'
WHERE dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID = " & gsVariable5 & ")
AND " & strFilter & "
AND dbo_tbl_ThisForm.Testfall_ID NOT IN
    (SELECT dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Testfall_ID
    FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions1
    WHERE dbo_tbl_Restrictions1.Auftrags_ID IN
        (SELECT Auftrag_ID
        FROM dbo_tbl_Restrictions2
        WHERE Auftragstyp = " & Me.kfAuftragstyp & "))
```

Maybe it's having a problem with the nested query?  Also, can you tell us exactly what the error your getting is?  You might want to put a code break in just before the UPDATE statement and run it for something you know works, and check what Access thinks strFilter is, then do it again for the one you're having trouble with and compare the values fo strFilter.  Make sure they're logical, and that the column they're restricting is spelled correctly and the value exists.

Comment: Thanks already for your effort and thoughts. Repositioning the filter doesn't change anything. I added the error-message and the value of `strFilter` when it works - please take a look at the edit.

Comment: How about this.  It requires an extra step, but set that whole Update statement equal to a variable.  Like, **Set strSQL = "UPDATE dbo_tbl_ThisForm..."**.  Then, you can do a **DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)** to run the code.  The benefit is, if you put a code break in there, you can see exactly what the SQL string is before it tries to run it.  Make sure anything that should be an Integer is an Integer, anything that should be a Text is a Text, etc...  You can also print the value of strSQL to the Immediate window, and then copy/paste that into a blank query and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I forgot to mention in my question, that I have already tried this. The second query I posted is just like the query that VBA generates, just that the last line is `AND ((Lookup_Programm__IDFS.Name="ad1incl"))`. If I run that in a blank query it just asks for the Parameter for **Lookup_Programm_...** and when I enter something it's like there's no restriction. The problem is the filter by form. It generates that strange **Lookup_Progra...Name** thingy, which I don't understand. There is no such field. Also the database is an external MSSQL-DB. But I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: Are you positive that **Lookup_Programm__IDFS** is the name of a table?  I don't see it in the SELECT statement.  If it's the name of the form, then it needs to be preceeded by **Forms!**.  Or, you can replace it with **Me.** if it's the current form that's open.

Comment: Also, you haven't shown us any code detailing how **strFilter** is generated.

Comment: No, that's exactly the point. I don't know what **Lookup_Programm__IDFS** is. The above mentioned (value of strFilter) is the Filter of the Form in the screenshot. That's also how strFiler is generated `strFilter = Me.Filter`.

Comment: See if there is a Filter property on the form.  My guess is, it's got that Lookup_Programm__IDFS in it.  If it's there, wipe it out.  If that doesn't help, in the Form.Load event, put **Me.Filter = ""** in there to clear out the form filter.

Comment: Sorry, that I'm answering now - I wasn't at the office.
I think you got something wrong there. that `Lookup_Programm_IDFS` **is** in the Filter of the form. It's also supposed to be there, since I only want to mark those 6 entries.
My question is, how I can use the existing form-filter in my VBA-SQL-Query. Why does Access put that `Lookup_` in front of the fieldname? Is it because of the data type or maybe because the control is a combo box? 
Thanks for your patience.